# How to always redirect to subfolder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect visitors who are viewing index (not other files) to a sub folder in every conidition. At the moment I'm using the code below in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^$ /dir [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But it only works on the main domain but doesn't work when we have the script itself in a subfolder. How should I modify this code to works everywhere?

---

The previous code works like below when installed on the root folder:

```
http://www.domain.com => http://www.domain.com/dir
```

Which is fine, but when we have it on sub, it works like below:

```
http://www.domain.com/sub => http://www.domain.com/dir
```

That means it move one level up and then locate for dir and that's the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
# Change in subfolder:
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^$ dir [L,R=301]
```

In root .htaccess for each subfolder:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1/dir/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually it redirects to an absolute path which comes after domain name.

Comment: And now ? (I add `RewriteBase` to avoid that)

Comment: Clear the cache or try with other browser !

Comment: sub was an example, I mean every directory.

Comment: You have the script itself in a subfolder... change the name in the directory. Or you can use one code for root. I add that.